# Trigger on multiple jQuery events

Tags: jquery

I am running jQuery 1.9.1 and I want to trigger the same code on two events:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  alert("Same code here ...");
});

$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  alert("Same code here ...");
});
```

I were looking in to the "on" method but as far as I can see, it cannot trigger on two events with separate ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new function first like:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("Same code here ...");
}
```

and then pass the reference of the function to the jquery events like:

```
$('#myForm').submit(myFunction);
$('#mySelect').change(myFunction);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6T7Hf/)

Comment: With demo and even gave a good hint on "preventDefault" to disable submit action

Answer (score 3):

You need to write it as a separate function and register it with both the event handlers

```
function handler() {
    alert("Same code here ...");
}

$("#myForm").submit(handler);
$("#mySelect").change(handler):
```

Answer (score 0):

yup!!! one way is to create a seperate function

```
$("#myForm").submit(callThis);

$("#mySelect").change(callThis);

function callThis(){
  alert("Same code here ...");
};
```